# mod_rewrite question

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy

I would like to serve /foo and /foo/ locally, but proxy requests for /foo/* to a remote server. However, the following rule matches all of the above. What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteRule ^/foo/(.+)$ http://remote.host/$1 [P,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to escape for the first couple of conditions so that they don't all send them off to the remote host. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo$ /$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^foo/$ /$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^foo/([a-zA-Z0-9].*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L]
```

First rule checks the first condition to be plainly `/foo`. If so, stay at home.

Next test checks to see if it's not just `/foo/`. If so, again, stay local.

Last test checks to see if you have anything dangling behind a slash, if so, then you probably want the remote host and sends it there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since mod_rewrite normally strips leading slashes from the matched text, I suspect you're either transcribing/anonymizing imperfectly or there's a good deal else going on in your rewrite configuration.  That seems further borne out by the impossibility of the pattern /foo/.+ matching /foo.

Can you expand and double-check what you're posting from your rewrite config, so we can see what else might be going on?

Comment: Here's a verbatim copy/paste, I'm testing with dummy values. /foo, /foo/, and /foo/blah all return proxy errors rather than local 404s.

    <VirtualHost *:80> 
      DocumentRoot /srv/proxytest 
      RewriteEngine On 
      RewriteRule ^/foo/(.+)$ http://remote.host/$1 [P,L] 
    </VirtualHost>

Comment: What's the proxy error?  Right now I'm suspecting that Apache is getting as far as reading the P in your options, trying to initialize its communication with mod_proxy, and dying before it actually does anything with your rule.

Comment: Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /foo/blah.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: remote.host

Comment: Okay, guess not then.  I assume for the mysterious requests to /foo and /foo/ it says GET /?  Well, that makes no sense, but we can probably work around it.  Try adding this before your current rule: RewriteRule ^/foo/?$ - [L]

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it -- somewhere the default docname is being set to index.php, which is silently being appended to my rewrite.

RewriteLog output:

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /foo
(3) applying pattern '^/foo(/.+)+$' to uri '/foo'
(1) pass through /foo
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /foo/
(3) applying pattern '^/foo(/.+)+$' to uri '/foo/'
(1) pass through /foo/
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /foo/index.php
(3) applying pattern '^/foo(/.+)+$' to uri '/foo/index.php'
(2) rewrite '/foo/index.php' -> 'http://remote.host//index.php'
(2) forcing proxy-throughput with http://remote.host//index.php
(1) go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://remote.host//index.php [OK]
```

Comment: Heh.  Check for .htaccess files.  Five bucks says you're using Wordpress.

Comment: No .htaccess, no Wordpress. But this is a VM I use to test various & sundry things, so although I removed all non-standard .conf files it's still possible something is hanging around causing trouble. Thanks for the help!